# Introductory text for calculus of variations

Tags: reference-request, soft-question, calculus-of-variations, book-recommendation

I am currently working on problems that require familiarity with calculus of variations. I am fairly new to this field. Please suggest a good introductory book for the same that could help me pick up the concepts quickly.

edit:
I would prefer books which are available in PDF format online.

Comment: Do you have access to a library? Sometimes they have books available digitally that might otherwise be unavailable (legally).

Comment: @Nick I do have access to the university library.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If you check out Wikipedia's entry on "Calculus of Variations: [**here**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calculus_of_variations), and scroll down to the bottom where "References" are listed:

- You'll find a link to a pdf reference (Jon Fischer, [***Introduction to the Calculus of Variation***](http://www2.math.uu.se/~gunnar/varcalc.pdf), a quick and readable guide) that might be exactly what you're looking for, as well as some additional references (sample problems, guides, etc.).
- In addition, you'll find a link to [**this site**](http://staff.www.ltu.se/~tomas/applmath/chap3en/index.htm) listed among the references.
- There's also a chapter of a text that's available online: [***Chapter 8: Calculus of Variation***](http://www.mpri.lsu.edu/textbook/Chapter8-b.htm) from [Optimization for Engineering Systems](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00BF2TLXO), by Ralph W. Pike.

There are also some additional texts and resources listed in the linked Wikipedia's entry, as well.

Comment: The links in your 2nd and third bullet points are dead.

Comment: The paper in the first link, albeit good, needs some edits... e.g. the diffeq in Theorem 1 — the most important Theorem — is wrong!

Comment: @wcochran it would be great if you could also share what's wrong. Thanks!

Comment: The diff eq at the bottom of page 5 should be \partial f / \partial y - d/dx (\partial f / \partial y') = 0. I am sure it's just a typo, but kind of important to get the main equation right.

Answer (score 10):

I just purchased a copy of Gelfand and Fomin's [Calculus of Variations](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0486414485).  It's a Dover book, so it's really inexpensive (I paid $9, including shipping).

The book gets very good reviews, both on Amazon and [MathOverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/46319/beginners-text-on-calculus-of-variations/46379#46379).  Just from reading the first few pages, it looks quite promising.

Answer (score 6):

I know this post is old, but if anyone else is looking for a good, concise and intuitive introduction to the calculus of variations, the chapter 'calculus of variations' in Peter Olver's as yet unpublished 'Applied Mathematics' (well, the first 10 chapters *are* published as 'Applied Linear Algebra') is very readable.

As of September 2011, this chapter is available on Peter's website at http://www.math.umn.edu/~olver/appl.html

Answer (score 3):

Michael Struwe *[Variational Methods: Applications to Nonlinear Partial Differential Equations and Hamiltonian Systems](http://books.google.com/books?id=74xkWviDrE0C)*, Fourth Edition, Springer, 2008.

Answer (score 2):

One I *really* enjoy is [Calculus of Variations](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0521057124) by Jürgen Jost - he also has an awesome book on Partial Differential Equations!

Answer (score 1):

Charles MacCluer wrote a book on the subject in 2008 for students with a minimal background (basically calculus and some differential equations), *Calculus of Variations: Mechanics, Control and Other Applications*. I haven't seen the whole book,but what I **have** seen is excellent and very readable. MacCluer says in the introduction his goal was to write a book on the subject that doesn't replace the old classics, but updates and supplements them with a lot of real-world applications and without heavy prerequisites. From what I've seen, he's succeeded and best of all, the book's available from Dover in a cheap paperback. This might be just what you're looking for.

If you're looking for something more mathematicially sophisticated and up-to-date, you can try the book by Bruce Van Brunt.