# Good book for learning Calculus of Variations?

Tags: reference-request

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Introductory text for calculus of variations](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/44828/introductory-text-for-calculus-of-variations)

What is a good book for learning Calculus of Variations on your own?