# textbook on calculus of variation which focuses on the following topics

Tags: reference-request, calculus-of-variations, book-recommendation

I need a textbook (or set of online lecture notes)   on calculus of variation which focuses on the  ***following topics*** "**Variation of a functional, Euler-Lagrange equation, Necessary and sufficient conditions for extrema , 
Variational methods for boundary value problems in ordinary and partial differential equations**"?please suggest a text book which contains more solved problems on the above topics .

***what are the different methods to solve the boundary value problems in ordinary and partial differential equations?***

I'm entirely new to this subject. Someone please help ...

Comment: You might have a look at suggestions given [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/44828/introductory-text-for-calculus-of-variations) and [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1077548/reference-request-calculus-of-variations).